# How do I remove the border around a vega(-lite) plot?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

Vega/Vega Lite plots have a faint gray border around them... is it possible to remove this via a configuration parameter, or do I need to render as SVG and use CSS to do so?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can override the default cell style

```
"config": {
  "style": {
    "cell": {
      "stroke": "transparent"
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the view stroke

```
"config": {
  "view": {
     "stroke": "transparent"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Due to possible version changes since, only the first version worked, of course, one solution is good enough

Comment: It still works for me. https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QECJAroxrZLGxgA2hsNhgkPVACCayOysAmABwBfVQcnK0gAIXdPHABWKICg50gAYQirABZpALtDRwSAERScAE4ARjickIBRArAfUsDynEgAMWqojPV7CAaoAHFq4sKy4MaACWqfAHYhhIBJVq8-LIBdDUyjDAAnAGsQ9nQNtQ1IZCV4bk1GJWorA0NIAA8byAAzRmQxTRDMQMg8AE9CMgQtwNhclKZIGs7n8nq93p9Gp4fv9ASEAI6sdBKPDMHSMKiQ1YdKBnJSva76LLGN4AdxuWSMsDwG24WyBjWZWNghH2JzwkCyiwgi0WQA

Comment: Thanks Dominik! I'll circle back to it, tried it with vega, not vega-lite though